# Return the value from Anonymous Function

Tags: flutter, dart

When I use anonymous function.

It shows compile error,

`Error: A value of type 'Text Function()' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'.`

```
Widget cols = Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    ((){
      if (myFlg){
        return Text("OK");
      }else {
        return Text("No");
      }
    }),
    Text("left"),
    Text("Right")
  ]
);
```

OK I understood.
It returns the function itself , not `Text()` Widget.

However, in this case, how can I return the Text() from anonymous function??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, almost. Your forgot to execute your function:

```
(() {
  if (myFlg) {
    return Text("OK");
  } else {
    return Text("No");
 }
})(),
```

Note that your can actually put if statements in collections so in this example you can avoid anonymous function and do this:

```
Widget cols = Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    if (myFlg) Text("OK") else Text("No"),
    Text("left"),
    Text("Right")
  ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks quick response and help, I was almost there, but I couldn't find the right answer for a long time....

Answer (score 2):

The execution of the function closure in Dart is as follows.

```
function_closure()
```

So you should add "()" after the function closure.

Example:

```
void main() {  
  print(() {
    return 41;
  });

  print(() {
    return 41;
  }());  
}
```

Result:

```
Closure: () => int
41
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer,  It is very easy understand but maybe 41 -> 21 ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yes.